# Detecting what Server Roles are installed on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012

In Windows Server 2008 you could programmatically detect server Features and Roles using WMI and the Win32_ServerFeature class.

In Windows Server 2012 the Win32_ServerFeature class has been deprecated and does not include features and roles new to 2012.

As far as i can tell [Win32_ServerFeature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc280268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class has been replace by [Server Manager Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh872518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and there are no examples of how to use it.

I have search online an can't find any info on it other than the docs that are no help.

Any assistance would be appreciated, i am developing in c# in a 4.5 Dot Net Framework Application.

Answer (score 9):

The way i would consider doing it is by using a piece of PowerShell script and then 'playing' with the output in C#.

If you add a reference to the following item you will be able to interact with PowerShell scripts in C# :

> System.Management.Automation

Then use the following *using* statements to delve into and interact with the features of this :

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
```

The following script will create a nice sub that will take a PowerShell command and return a readable string, with each item (in this case, a role) added as a new line :

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
// create a Powershell runspace then open it

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

// create a pipeline and add it to the text of the script

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

// format the output into a readable string, rather than using Get-Process
// and returning the system.diagnostic.process

pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

// execute the script and close the runspace

Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();

// convert the script result into a single string

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}

return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Then you can pass the following PowerShell command to the script and receieve the output like so :

```
RunScript("Import-module servermanager | get-windowsfeature");
```

Alternatively you could just run this PowerShell command from a C# script and then read the output text file from C# when the script has finished processing :

```
import-module servermanager | get-windowsfeature > C:\output.txt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah.  I figured it out in PS quite easily. I'm tempted to actually rearchitect the whole thing and do it in Powershell..  Presuming I can compile that down to an Exe file..

Comment: Yeah, why not! With the above procedure you can pipe any PowerShell command through C# and still have the option for a nice GUI, plus the options for interacting with the network / OS are almost endless with PowerShell. Anything you cant achieve through PowerShell, you just use odd bits of C#.
Im glad this worked anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend you to check Windows Registry. For example for components of IIS you can check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components` folder